# How to decode this byte string from a file?

Tags: python, file, unicode, binaryfiles, binary-data

I used code provided by someone on the stackoverflow to read a binary file. The code is:

```
with open('OutputFile', 'rb') as f:
  text = f.read()
```

I printed text and it appeared as below. Now I need to decode them into binary data, much like `01010010...`.
I used `text.decode('utf-8')` to decode the text, but it showed error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

How to solve this issue? How to read them into binary strings?

```
b'\x88\xc6\xe7\x1a3\'1(\xd2\xb7*\xa5{a\xac\x0f\xabf\\\xe9Z\xa4\xb0\x116v\xe0}\xc5\xb8\xe1P\xf1\x01\xd7\xf63\x11\xec\xe7\xb7\xbeG\xaa\xdf\xd87\xdaK\x9c?\xe8\x0e\x84\xce|%\xcb\xc0\x1d\xe4\xe4\x02#c\xb1\xd0o\x1da\x87\nW\xb9\xc9\xb2\x08\x1c\xffP,4\x86\'\xecx$\x05\xa2\x1b\x8d\xc9\xe9\x12(t\xcba\xa5\xc9H\xb5[X\xf9\xdd\xa7q\x8e\x92r\xe2T\xe0a*\x13$\xdaS\x8bx\r\xc1\xa9~\xb7\xd8-\xef&\xad\xa8\xdd\xe5\x1d#\x99`\xa0\xb7\xbc\xe1\x96;:@SG\xea\xd2]\xfc\xc02\xb9\x01\xbe%\xbb?\x99\x0e\xa0{7Z\xa3\xa4\xcb\xe4\xe0C%1\xaf\xcb\x1e\xb3\xc6\xb1\xd7\xf8,,\x08\xc0\'\xbf\xde\xb5\xe3)~$\x05\x8c>\x88\xb8`\xce\xe3\x1a\x97zs\x05\x91\xcd\xee\xb9^S\x8c\x8f=\x0f\xe6\xf5TZ\xb24c\xf0YZ\xac\xf9\x87\x05,\x04\xf7>\x0c\xf6c/t\xbayB\x06\x0cd\x0f\x15\x1eZ\x9c#\xb7\\-\x16A\x06@\r\x12\x19\x85YV\xb3\x7f$\xc4}\xab\xda\xf5\xebO\xcf@/\x1ea\xa7\x03E\xb3\xef4\x11\x05hCJF(\x93\r\xb9\xa6\x84\x15\x8a\xda\xbe\x12\xff\xd2\xa5\x19y\xea\xb5H\xbd\x97\xc8\x81\xd5\'\xadN\xd8s\x0c\x0f\x97\xcb3d\xfa\xf6&\n\xdc\xd5\xd4\x15\x87\x08\xcb\xeb\xb4\x07\xf8)IE\xfd\x1am_C\xf2x\x04a\xa8\xdc\xb3G\xa4\xeaq6O\xe6D\xb4]d\x93\x95`\xe6W\xe2w\xc8^\t\xdc\x13aJE\xafU];V\x1f\xda\x96\xc8t\xdfk\x96\xc6\xd5\xc0B.\xeb\xac)<\xa7F\xce\x0c\xf1\xf1v\x18\xba\xf6^@0\x14\x1c#\xc7r\x86\xc4\xd6\x0e\xca\x94c\xf8m!\xeb57\xc7P\t\x1a\xed\xc8#7h\xc2\x03\xd9M\xdf\xdd\x05\x7f\xecS\x1c\xd4\xca\x84\xf5\xb3\xe5<\x1f\xb5\x05\xd8$\x8dC_J\n\x89\xe7\x8b\xb7\x00\x95\xe9\x8ct!\xe8\xf3\x82|\x9f|6ORa_J\x9c*\xf9\x0b\x1emV\x91\x93#\x91+\x18^wfK\x01\xc8\xd7&[\x13\xeb[\xb8\x0b\xf0.8\xb1\t)@\xc5H\xa0O0H"n\xeaQ\xc0p\xdaZm\xf0A^\xed)m\xd2\xef[$\xce\x9d\xd9\x97\xd3K\xdc\x1c\xeb\x17\xc4\x0e-\xc7p\xe5\x7f\xcf\xa5l\x95q\xb9\xe7WB2\xb5\x8c\xf3\xdf_\xea\x02\x1cx5\x92>\xf1\xcec\x9b\x01\xd3\xa8\x89\xb6\x85O\x04\xd4W\xe5\xfa\t\xe6-\xaa?r\x166\xe6\xed\x80\xf4\xe2\xe6\x83\x0f\xae!\xc7C\xff@'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [how not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before posting a question. We need to understand the problem correctly *and* entirely so please add all the necessary details that clarify your issue and/or (when related to code) post a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MCRE) with the actual and expected behavior as well as (if possible) the actual input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is already in binary format interally since you read the file in mode `"rb"`. Here's how to print it out as 0s and 1s:

```
with open('OutputFile', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

binary = ''.join(('{:08b}'.format(byte) for byte in data))
print(binary)
```

Output:

```
1000100011000110111001110001101000110011001001110011000100101000110100101011011100101010101001010111101101100001101011000000111110101011011001100101110011101001010110101010010010110000000100010011011001110110111000000111110111000101101110001110000101010000111100010000000111010111111101100011001100010001111011001110011110110111101111100100011110101010110111111101100000110111110110100100101110011100001111111110100000001110100001001100111001111100001001011100101111000000000111011110010011100100000000100010001101100011101100011101000001101111000111010110000110000111000010100101011110111001110010011011001000001000000111001111111101010000001011000011010010000110001001111110110001111000001001000000010110100010000110111000110111001001111010010001001000101000011101001100101101100001101001011100100101001000101101010101101101011000111110011101110110100111011100011000111010010010011100101110001001010100111000000110000100101010000100110010010011011010010100111000101101111000000011011100000110101001011111101011011111011000001011011110111100100110101011011010100011011101111001010001110100100011100110010110000010100000101101111011110011100001100101100011101100111010010000000101001101000111111010101101001001011101111111001100000000110010101110010000000110111110001001011011101100111111100110010000111010100000011110110011011101011010101000111010010011001011111001001110000001000011001001010011000110101111110010110001111010110011110001101011000111010111111110000010110000101100000010001100000000100111101111111101111010110101111000110010100101111110001001000000010110001100001111101000100010111000011000001100111011100011000110101001011101111010011100110000010110010001110011011110111010111001010111100101001110001100100011110011110100001111111001101111010101010100010110101011001000110100011000111111000001011001010110101010110011111001100001110000010100101100000001001111011100111110000011001111011001100011001011110111010010111010011110010100001000000110000011000110010000001111000101010001111001011010100111000010001110110111010111000010110100010110010000010000011001000000000011010001001000011001100001010101100101010110101100110111111100100100110001000111110110101011110110101111010111101011010011111100111101000000001011110001111001100001101001110000001101000101101100111110111100110100000100010000010101101000010000110100101001000110001010001001001100001101101110011010011010000100000101011000101011011010101111100001001011111111110100101010010100011001011110011110101010110101010010001011110110010111110010001000000111010101001001111010110101001110110110000111001100001100000011111001011111001011001100110110010011111010111101100010011000001010110111001101010111010100000101011000011100001000110010111110101110110100000001111111100000101001010010010100010111111101000110100110110101011111010000111111001001111000000001000110000110101000110111001011001101000111101001001110101001110001001101100100111111100110010001001011010001011101011001001001001110010101011000001110011001010111111000100111011111001000010111100000100111011100000100110110000101001010010001011010111101010101010111010011101101010110000111111101101010010110110010000111010011011111011010111001011011000110110101011100000001000010001011101110101110101100001010010011110010100111010001101100111000001100111100011111000101110110000110001011101011110110010111100100000000110000000101000001110000100011110001110111001010000110110001001101011000001110110010101001010001100011111110000110110100100001111010110011010100110111110001110101000000001001000110101110110111001000001000110011011101101000110000100000001111011001010011011101111111011101000001010111111111101100010100110001110011010100110010101000010011110101101100111110010100111100000111111011010100000101110110000010010010001101010000110101111101001010000010101000100111100111100010111011011100000000100101011110100110001100011101000010000111101000111100111000001001111100100111110111110000110110010011110101001001100001010111110100101010011100001010101111100100001011000111100110110101010110100100011001001100100011100100010010101100011000010111100111011101100110010010110000000111001000110101110010011001011011000100111110101101011011101110000000101111110000001011100011100010110001000010010010100101000000110001010100100010100000010011110011000001001000001000100110111011101010010100011100000001110000110110100101101001101101111100000100000101011110111011010010100101101101110100101110111101011011001001001100111010011101110110011001011111010011010010111101110000011100111010110001011111000100000011100010110111000111011100001110010101111111110011111010010101101100100101010111000110111001111001110101011101000010001100101011010110001100111100111101111101011111111010100000001000011100011110000011010110010010001111101111000111001110011000111001101100000001110100111010100010001001101101101000010101001111000001001101010001010111111001011111101000001001111001100010110110101010001111110111001000010110001101101110011011101101100000001111010011100010111001101000001100001111101011100010000111000111010000111111111101000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am a student and struggling with such things. Would you mind to recommend some resources to master these things using Python?

Comment: Pei Y: You're welcome. It's been so long since I was a student, I'm not really up-to-date on good current resources. I learned a lot of Python stuff from a series of books titled the "Python Cookbook" published by O'Reilly & Associates. Nowadays there are many online Python tutorials, so I'm sure you can find something decent with a little web searching.

Comment: Thank you! I want to upvote your answer. But it shows, 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.'

Comment: Although you cannot up-vote it yet, you should be able to accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark ✓ character (it's **below** the two vote buttons).

Comment: Done. Thank you!